# VBA - Replace only a single whitespace (" ") in a string with a character

Tags: excel, vba, string, replace, whitespace

I have a string with the following text:

`16/2730 99    16/2730 97    16/2730 81    16/2730 76    16/2730 103    16/2730 102    16/2730 101`

I would like to replace the single whitespaces (" ") with another character "-". My desired result would be:

`16/2730-99    16/2730-97    16/2730-81    16/2730-76    16/2730-103    16/2730-102    16/2730-101`

Any suggestions on how to replace the single whitespaces with another character, while leaving the multiple whitespaces alone?

Comment: Brute force approach - loop over the string using `Instr(yourString, " ")` and look for cases where the character preceding and following the space are both digits (or surrounding characters are both non-space).  a Regexp solution would also work - google "VBA regexp replace" for examples

Comment: ...or if it's always the same multiple of spaces then do something like `Replace(myText, "    ","~~~~")` then   `Replace(myText, " ","-")` then `Replace(myText, "~~~~", "    ")`

Comment: Posted another approach in addition to @TimWilliams 's valid tips to get to the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A further approach in addition to Tim Williams' valid tips in comments might be the following one *(assuming search sequences of digits, slashes and single blanks `" "` which can be identified as numeric)*:

- Split the string by blanks into a variant array,
- add a hyphen to elements with a numeric right neighbour only,
- fill ""-elements with a blank again and
- join the array setting the delimiter to `""`.

**Example**

```
Sub Example()
    Dim s As String
    s = "16/2730 99    16/2730 97    16/2730 81    16/2730 76    16/2730 103    16/2730 102    16/2730 101"

    Dim tmp As Variant
    tmp = Split(s)
    'Debug.Print Join(tmp, "|")                  ' optional display in immediate window
    'Loop through splitted array elements
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(tmp) - 1
        If IsNumeric(tmp(i + 1)) Then            ' if immediate right neighbour is numeric
            tmp(i) = tmp(i) & "-"                ' .. add a hyphen to the current element
        ElseIf tmp(i) = "" Then                  ' if current element was a blank
            ' .. give back the former blank values (<~~ Edited ~~>)
            tmp(i) = IIf(IsNumeric(Right(tmp(i + 1), 1)), "  ", " ")
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print Join(tmp, "")                    ' put completed elements together again

End Sub
```

*Results in VB Editor's immediate window*

`16/2730-99    16/2730-97    16/2730-81    16/2730-76    16/2730-103    16/2730-102    16/2730-101`

Comment: That solved it, thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome; please note the edit of the `tmp(i)` assignment (in code line after `ElseIf`) in order to return *all* remaining blanks *(instead of reducing them by one)*  @spardacus